# uwsgi + django import error

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have a problem when I use django with uwsgi with the pythonpath.

I have a django project named 'project' which is the /sites/django/ directory

So to start uwsgi i use this command :

```
/opt/uwsgi/uwsgi -s 127.0.0.1:9001 -C -M 4 -t 30 -A 4 -p 4 -d /var/log/uwsgi.log --pythonpath '/sites/django/project/' --module wsgi
```

If I am in the /sites/django/project' it works.

If I start a python shell and I write :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/sites/django/project/')
import wsgi
```

It works too.

But when i launch the uwsgi command outside the /sites/django/project/ I have the error :

> ImportError: No module named wsgi

So I don't know why I have the ImportError : it works in the shell.

If anyone has an idea, 
Thanks.

Well, i find the answer, it seems it's a bug and i must add the "-i" option (single interpreter mode ) in my command .

Comment: The `--pythonpath` option specifies where to find packages, so this is not the directory where your main file wsgi file is but a `site-packages` directory, either from your user, system, or from the virtual environment. Look through the different sections of the documentation of the configuration options: https://uwsgi-docs-additions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc) seems to suggest two possibilities.

First, remove the single quotes from the python path argument.  Second, the examples on the linked page have `--python-path` instead of `--pythonpath` (even though the index at the top of the page says otherwise).  Worth trying.

Comment: thanks, but python-path is not a recognized option and without the quotes does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a virtualenv, you need to pass in the -H flag ( http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnv )